# angularjs - orderBy custom comparator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display a list of values based on an order-function that may require comparing more than 1 field, so the standard one-parameter function is not sufficient for me.

I want items with a description to be on the top of the list (no matter what the description is) and among the top half (with description) and the bottom half (without description) I want an alphabetical order by the name.

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:memberSort">
  {{item.sortName}} / {{item.description}}
</div>
```

and the comparator:

```
$scope.memberSort = function(m1, m2) {
    if (m1.description && !m2.description) {
       return -1;
    }
    if (m2.description && !m1.description) {
       return 1;
    }
    return m1.sortName.localCompare(m2.sortName);
};
```

how can I use a comparator like this and not just a one-parameter value function? In above code, the parameter m2 is always undefined.

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwg4s2r/15/

while this is just 1 current problem, the general question is how to define a comparator function accepting 2 values and not just a single-parameter function that maps a complex object to a value?

Comment: if it is so, then I have no idea how to apply that solution to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had to specify `memberSort` comparator as a third argument of `orderBy`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [    
    { description: '', sortName: 'Bob' },
    { description: '', sortName: 'Steve' },
    { description: '', sortName: 'Mark' },
    { description: 'Member', sortName: 'Kirk' },
    { description: 'Boss', sortName: 'Joe' }
  ];
  $scope.memberSort = function(o1, o2) {
    var m1 = o1.value, m2 = o2.value;
    if (m1.description && !m2.description)
       return -1;    
    if (m2.description && !m1.description)
       return 1;    
    return m1.sortName.localeCompare(m2.sortName);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'valueOf()' : false : memberSort">  
    {{item.sortName}} / {{item.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I was looking for something that does the trick like valueOf(). I tried working with '', null and false, just with no success.

Comment: hmmm.... while this seems to work with your posted code, I can't get it to work either in my jsfiddle or at home. The memberSort function is never called.

Comment: I guess my angular version is maybe too low. I'll go with the other answer then

Comment: @The.Bear, are you sure, that it not works with angular 1.6.0? What about [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwg4s2r/80/)? You loaded angularjs library twice: at first 1.6.0 and then 1.2.1(< 1.5.7). Also you wrong copied `memberSort` function from my answer. Please, be more attentive.

Answer (score 3):

Since angularjs 1.5.7, the [Angularjs OrderBy pipe can take a function as comparator](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy), but I think that is much simpler bind a function that return the sorted array using JavaScript [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort).

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwg4s2r/86/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getSortedItems()">
  {{item.sortName}} / {{item.description}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
      {description: 'Boss',sortName: 'Joe'},
      //... rest of your items
   ];

   $scope.getSortedItems = function() {
       return $scope.items.sort(function(m1, m2) {
           if (m1.description && !m2.description)
               return -1;

           if (m2.description && !m1.description)
               return 1;

           return m1.sortName.localeCompare(m2.sortName);
       });
   };
}
```

---

*If case if you care about performance, **do not use angularjs filters to do simple tasks** like sort an array. While in my solution, the sort function is executed twice (would be better if you can sort the array an then assign the value to a binded variable), in the accepted solution is executed 20 times.*